# QJsonDocument from json

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have a binary string with JSON object that I need to parse. But when I create `QJsonDocument` from it I get an empty document. I've tried to read an error code after creating but `QJsonParseError` contains "NoError". JSON that I want to parse is too large, but when I try to create small json and parse it I end up with same result. My short example:

```c++
QJsonDocument doc;
QString json("{\"key\" : \"value\"}");
QJsonParseError error;
doc.fromJson(json.toUtf8(), &error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QJsonDocument::fromJson()` is a static function. So you can call it without an object and this function have no access to non-static class members. To initialize document with given json:

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json.toUtf8(), &error);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! It works, I knew that miss some small detail.